# Do all LDAP servers have anonymous access?

Tags: authentication, ldap

I need to configure programmatic ldap authentication in an application. But I'd rather not hardcode passwords anywhere. So it would be very convenient if ldap servers all have anonymous access for authentication purposes.

Being a bit new to ldap, this might look like a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to deactivate anonymous binds on [open]ldap

Comment: It's not that I want to deactivate it. :-) I just need to know whether it's realistic to expect ldap servers to provide anonymous access. It's for setting up authentication of a web application.

Comment: Ifthe administrator has not disabled it (which is possible) you can assume the ldap has anonymous bind enabled. You cannot assume it has anonymous binding enabled, because it is possible to disable it.